# WebdriverIO:cucumber setup shows error "Cannot read property length of undefined" when running tests

Tags: node.js, selenium, cucumber, webdriver-io

I'm kind of stuck with this for a while now. I'm trying to get into testing with webdriverIO cucumber setup and found docs and an example at the webdriverIO website which I'm trying to get running: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/tree/master/examples/wdio.

I'm pretty sure I followed instructions correctly but I keep getting the following error after I run wdio wdio.conf.js:

```
    [01:31:40]:  DATA                {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"firefox"
    ,"version":"","javascriptEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":true,"handlesAle
    rts":true,"rotatable":true,"platform":"ANY","loggingPrefs":{"browser":"ALL","dri
    ver":"ALL"},"requestOrigins":{"url":"http://webdriver.io","version":"3.4.0","nam
    e":"webdriverio"}}}

[01:32:03]:  SET SESSION ID d9d12d43-2bd2-48e1-979c-847a44c10ccd

ERROR: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

browserName: "firefox"
```

Any ideas anyone?

I've installed the following npm packages:

```
"cucumber": "^0.9.4",
"selenium-standalone": "^4.8.0",
"webdriverio": "^3.4.0"
```

running npm version 2.14.12 and node 4.2.6 on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading it to cucumber 0.7.0 worked for me

Comment: Thank you @Sim_8! Works like a charm now!